# awaiting two things in a loop?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

How can I await for two or more things (with different types) at the same time? Like in an event loop:

```
while(true) {
    Letter msg1 = await WaitForLetter();
    //read msg1 and reply.
    SMS msg2 = await WaitForSMS();
    //read msg2 and reply
}
```

That doesn't look right. The two messages will end up blocking each other?

Comment: You can use `WaitAll` or `WaitAny`, but unless there's going to be one letter for every sms why have them in the same infinite loop at all?

Comment: You could put them in two while loops... in the infinite loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, your code will wait for each method to finish in turn. If you want to send out each message then wait for both at the end, you can use the [`Task.WaitAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx) method (assuming your methods return a `Task<T>` object.

```
while(true) {
    Task<Letter> msgTask1 = WaitForLetter();
    Task<SMS> msgTask2 = WaitForSMS();

    Task.WaitAll(msgTask1, msgTask2);
}
```

You can then get the result of each task with the `Result` property (again assuming your method return `Task<T>`:

```
Letter msg1 = msgTask1.Result;
SMS msg2 = msgTask2.Result;
```

Of course, this all assumes the implementation of `WaitForLetter` and `WaitForSMS` are independent and don't block each other.

If you just want to wait for *any* of the tasks to finish, you can use [`Task.WaitAny'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270672(v=vs.110).aspx) to much the same end. This returns the index of the task that finished so you know which one is complete.

```
while(true) {
    Task<Letter> msgTask1 = WaitForLetter();
    Task<SMS> msgTask2 = WaitForSMS();

    var finishedTask = Task.WaitAny(msgTask1, msgTask2);
}
```

Comment: why do you need while(true) ?

Comment: It's in his code, there could be more code he hasn't posted. The pertinent part is the `WaitAll`.

Comment: The problem though is that I might get one SMS an hour but only one letter a month. So I cant wait for all. Id like to wait for any. I'm not sure how to do this, when the tasks are of different type, etc

Comment: @someoneelse then you're in luck! There's a [`Task.WaitAny`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270672(v=vs.110).aspx) method which does just that, waits until any of the tasks are complete then moves on. You'll have to add some validation around which task is finished and make sure you don't run into issues, but it's available.

Comment: Thanks. Does Task.WaitAny work even for task of different types? As in I can put a Task<Letter> and a Task<SMS> in a Task[] array? I guess I got to create an array of Task<Object> and then cast to the correct type afterwards. (I'm a C++ programmer so and not very familiar with C# variable type arrays)

Comment: @someoneelse just FYI , while probably this answer may work for you , in certain cases you may need to use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on each task before awaiting both with `Task.WaitAny`

Comment: The question asks for a way to do this *asynchronously*.  You're waiting *synchronously*.

Comment: @Servy I'm not quite sure what you mean, at some point you're going to have to wait for the tasks to complete. The entire section could itself be in an `async` method so it doesn't block the main thread.

Comment: @Steve `at some point you're going to have to wait for the tasks to complete`  No, that's not true.  If the program is fundamentally asynchronous, then there is nothing synchronously waiting on it.  The method the OP is writing is clearly already an `async` method.  We know this because he's using `await` in it, so it *must* already be marked `async`.

Answer (score 4):

I think that your best option here is to use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "Rx-Main"). It works very nicely with Tasks.

Here's the code that you need:

```
var subscription1 =
    Observable
        .FromAsync(WaitForLetter)
        .Repeat()
        .Subscribe(msg1 =>
        {
            //read msg1 and reply.
        });

var subscription2 =
    Observable
        .FromAsync(WaitForSMS)
        .Repeat()
        .Subscribe(msg2 =>
        {
            //read msg2 and reply
        });
```

Both run independently of each other and both run asynchronously.

To stop them running simply do this:

```
subscription1.Dispose();
subscription2.Dispose();
```

If you actually want them to run like an event loop, whereby messages both come in on the same thread, interspersed with each other, then you can do this:

```
var eventLoopScheduler = new EventLoopScheduler();

var subscription1 =
    Observable
        .FromAsync(WaitForLetter)
        .Repeat()
        .ObserveOn(eventLoopScheduler)
        .Subscribe(msg1 =>
        {
            //read msg1 and reply.
        });

var subscription2 =
    Observable
        .FromAsync(WaitForSMS)
        .Repeat()
        .ObserveOn(eventLoopScheduler)
        .Subscribe(msg2 =>
        {
            //read msg2 and reply
        });
```

You have a little more clean-up, but this can be handled nicely with this:

```
var subscriptions = new CompositeDisposable(
    subscription1,
    subscription2,
    eventLoopScheduler);

//then later

subscriptions.Dispose();
```

Comment: If there is real need for event loop here, RX is really need and lean on the code solution to use.

Comment: @vittore - Sorry, can you explain what you mean by, "need and lean on the code solution to use"?

Comment: That looks very clean. You guys in the C# world are years ahead compared to C++ when it comes to asynchrony. Im a bit jealous. We will finally get await and coroutines in the next C++ standard. Few C++ programmers know how to use await yet. So thats why I ended up asking about how to use C# await. I'm hoping we will get some nice frameworks similar to Linq and Rx built on top of coroutines in C++. But we will probably have to wait years for that.

Comment: @Enigmativity it was typo: "nice and lean on the code solution"